# HTML5 video autoplay and autostop when specific class on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, slider

I have an slider of videos, I want to autoplay when visible and autostop when not visible. The visible video at the moment of stay visible has a class (active) that identifies it.

```
<video class="item active" controls autoplay poster="" width="640" height="360">
<video class="item" controls autoplay poster="" width="640" height="360">
<video class="item" controls autoplay poster="" width="640" height="360">
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trigger the events on my slider when translates an initialize a slide an then execute these functions:

When translate:

```
function(){
           $('.item').find('video').each(function(){
               this.pause();
           });
```

When initialize a new slide (to automatically play it):

```
function(){
           $('.active').find('video').each(function(){
               this.play();
           });
```

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the states of video with javascript.
For playing for example you can select the video tag that have class active and play it:

```
document.querySelector('video.active').play();
```

For any other video tags you can just pause them with this code:

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video.item');
for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i].pause();
}
```

You will need to make this manipulation on click, or on slide change, and also take note that first you will need to stop all videos then just play the video with active class.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved triggering the events on the slider when translated and initialized a new slide.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("video").prop("volume", 0.3).click(function() {
  this[this.paused ? "play" : "pause"]()
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).